# How to push "undo pushed commit" using command line?

Tags: git

EDIT: Ok so I work it out. The problem is how I stated the branch name. It's supposed to be `git push -f origin card-editor` instead of `git push -f origin/card-editor`. Thanks.

---

The majority of time I work with git, I use sourcetree. Except when "major disaster" things happened. This is one of the situation (for me). Long story short, I do a commit and push, but now I want to undo it on the local, as well as undo it on the remote.

I follow tutorial from [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/git/undo-pushed-commits-in-git/). I successfully `reset --hard` the head to the last good commit. Now it's just the matter of pushing it to the server.

The way the tutorial does it looks very simple.

```
git push -f branchname
```

My feature branch remote name is "card-editor". So I did it.

```
git push -f card-editor
```

But I got error that says "card-editor" does not appear to be a git repository.

I listed my list of branch with `git branch -r`.

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/card-editor
origin/development
origin/staging
origin/production
```

Alright, so I think the branch name is `origin/card-editor`. So I retry it.

```
git push -f origin/card-editor
```

But it still showing "origin/card-editor" does not appear to be a git repository.

What's wrong with my approach? I don't think there's something special that needs to be done here? I'm not particularly versed with Git, especially with console command, as usually I use sourcetree to manage it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen's answer is correct.  I'll point out that reverting a commit and pushing a branch to a remote are two separate issues.  If you can push a local branch to a remote before doing any kind of revert (either `git reset` or `git revert`), you should be able to do so afterwards as well.  Since you are ***rewriting  history*** when doing a `git reset`, you will need to add the `-f` option in the case of `git reset`.

Comment: @CryptoFool I indeed want to rewrite the history with -f, as the only one who works with this branch is only me. I suppose git revert works as well and I can do either this or that, but I just want to know why my git push -f doesn't work, or why it can't find the branch I stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have really already pushed the unwanted commit to the remote, then the safest approach here would be to *revert* the commit:

```
# assuming the unwanted commit is on the top of the branch
git revert HEAD
git push origin master
```

The command `git revert` adds a *new* commit which functionally undoes whatever change your commit introduced.  This approach is safer than `git reset` because the latter ****rewrites history****, and so is not suitable once the commit has already been pushed to the remote.